Is it impossible for something that exists to become non-existent?
If nothingness does not exist in any form, then everything that exists cannot become nothing, does that mean that everything that exists only changes form?

If I create a unique painting, then burn it, is the art I created now non-existent or has it changed forms, according to the definition of "existence/non-existence/changing form" you mean in your question?

No, phrasing does not have metaphysical powers. "Becomes nothing" is a figure of speech for something ceasing to exist, it does not mean that a thing called "nothing" comes into existence in return, see negative existential sentences. And things cease to exist all the time, electrons get annihilated by positrons, humans die, etc., so it is possible, see SEP, Nothingness.

Yes, with death a person ceases to exists, as a person. But if you play with words, asserting that there is only transformation from living being to atoms, then the point of view changes. What is "nothingness"? The absolute absence of being? What does it mean? How can you detect it? What properties can you predicate of it?

This is going to come down to your exact definition of 'something', 'become', and 'non-existent', which I know is an annoying answer, but it's also the correct one.

@Conifold The annihilation of electrons and positrons does not result in "nothingness" but just the conversion of energy from particles to photons.

Concerning the term “nothingness” our language is misleading.
There is no noun like “nothingness”. Instead, the noun “nothing” indicates a negation: “There is no thing with the property P”.
Example:

There is no unicorn = Nothing is a unicorn = There is no animal with a
single horn on its head.

It is risky to follow the language of the German philosopher Martin Heidegger who formed sentences about nothingness.
Added. My answer to your title question: It is possible that something which exists stops to exist: All living being will die and stop to exist.

The non-existence (or potentially impossibility) of nothingness does not imply that individual things can't cease to exist, because there'd still be other things. Ceasing to exist does not mean replacing the object with a "unit of nothingness" (whatever that would mean).
As for "ceasing to exist", it's not unreasonable to say things just change forms instead instead of actually truly physically ceasing to exist. When you burn something, that's a chemical reaction that changes something into ash and heat energy. When a person dies, they don't just pop out of existence, but rather them dying entails various chemical reactions (or the ceasing of those), and eventually their body will go through other chemical reactions (decomposition), which causes the matter to convert into other forms. If we want to be pedantic, one could point out that it's energy and mass that changes form. See also: the conservation of energy and mass. One could also point out that the conservation of energy can arguably be violated by general relativity on the cosmological scale, depending on the definitions used.
Although this is probably getting a bit too far into physics for this site.
If we're talking about all of everything ceasing to exist altogether, it doesn't seem too reasonable to think that would happen. Every moment we've perceived has been followed by another moment of things continuing to exist. The inductive conclusion is that this would continue happening. The closest one might get to that is the hypothesised heat death of the universe, although this doesn't imply "nothingness" in a philosophical sense (there may still be particles floating around, but just not enough energy to sustain processes).

Nothingness is the absence of anything, and as such it is incompatible with what we know, namely that there is something. All we can do if try to make sense of what the definition of the word says, and since our own existence as conscious being is antinomic with the idea of nothingness, it is for us probably an impossible task.

If nothingness does not exist in any form, then everything that exists cannot become nothing

Non sequitur.
The word "nothing" does not mean "nothingness" and has in fact very little to do with it. In order that there be nothing in the drawer, there has to be something, namely, the drawer.
We may say "There is nothing there", which implicitly says that there is something, namely "there", i.e., some sort of location.
We could say "There is nothing", but the "there" is still there, as it were. We just cannot conceive the idea that there is nothing without having in mind some location, which makes the idea that there is nothing antinomic with the idea of nothingness.
Nothing really means "no thing", but no thing in some place, not no thing at all.
The situation which existed a moment ago simply no longer exists, replaced no doubt by another situation, but no longer there itself, so certain things certainly cease to exist. These things may well be regarded as pure appearances or epiphenomena, but if we could remove all appearances, it seems that nothing we know of would remain. So most of the things which are familiar to us because they make up the furniture of the world we live in not only can cease to exist, but do cease to exist all the time.

does that mean that everything that exists only changes form?

Perhaps there is something fundamental which doesn't cease to exist, but for now we don't seem to actually know anything of that sort. I guess we can probably say that reality itself cannot possibly cease to exist, but I wouldn't bet on it.
